# Add schema.org markup to a video from Brightcove?

Tags: brightcove

Im embedding videos with brightcove. Google recommends that videos use schema.org markup:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/sitemaps

I can add most of this markup in my site however im not sure how to show "Raw video file URL and/or the video player URL". Does the brightcove API allow for this? I would have thought that this would be a common thing to do but I cant find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brightcove have provided their own Schema.org generator -
http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/cms-api/samples/schema-tool.html

Regarding the embedURL item, you can generate it using the endpoint below (you can also see this in their generator):

http://players.brightcove.net/ACCOUNT_ID/CLIENT_ID_default/index.html?videoId=VIDEO_ID

http://players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/28e29e6d-bed3-4db9-8d70-8d55b8aa3091_default/index.html?videoId=4454620113001